# FieldError at /add-to-cart/test-product1

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

Hello guys i need help here please, while trying my dd to cart button i received this message.

FieldError at /add-to-cart/test-product1/
Cannot resolve keyword 'ordered' into field. Choices are: id, item, item_id, order, quantity

```
my views.py for the add to cart function.

def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
        else:
            ordered_date = timezone.now()
            order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user, 
                           ordered_date=ordered_date)
            order.items.add(order_item)
        return redirect("store:product", slug=slug)
```

my models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.user.username
```

Comment: It means `ordered=False` does not exists as field. Note that this is the `OrderItem` model, not the `Order` model.

Comment: This is my order item model OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item.quantity} of {self.item.title}"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to perform a `get_or_create` on the `OrderItem` model. However, this model does not contain the field `ordered` (as confirmed in your comment). The field `ordered` only exists in the `Order` model, hence why Django will raise an exception saying that the field does not exist in the model.

Answer (score 0):

````
then include all naming's to your view.py.```

```my views```
```in the views.py in my cart function, I used the order, 
created method whereby i queried my Order Class model from my model.py. 
then I made sure that the object that is being called has also be 
mentioned also in my model class. just like the customer object. 
if the object been called hasn't been mentioned you are must
 likely to get a field error.```

    def cart(request):
        
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            customer = request.user.customer
            order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
            items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        else:
            items = []
    
        context = {'items':items}
        return render(request, 'shop/cart.html', context)
    
    class Order(models.Model):
        customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
        transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id)

    class OrderItem(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
        quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.product.id)
````

Comment: Hi there! So... it's a bad practice to "just put the code" in an answer. Could you add a little more context? Usually a small explanation of what you did would be enough. Thanks!

Comment: ok spersico. I am new here thou, but I made sure that my customer naming is exactly as what i used in my Order model. and that was what i used in my views.py in my cart func. when i did order or create method. if what u are calling in your order or create method in not cited in the exact model you are querying you are likely to get a field error. Thanks for the correction bro.

Comment: No worries, and you're welcome. Something to take into account for the next time :-)